# Convert Spark dataframe to an HDF5 file in Python

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdf5, h5py

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
+-------+---------------+------+
|col1   |col2           |col3  |
+-------+---------------+------+
|      1|              0|     0|
|      4|              0|     3|
|      4|              1|     1|
|      1|              2|     2|
+-------+---------------+------+
```

I would like to turn this dataframe into an HDF5 file in Python. The HDF5 file should have 3 keys `col1, col2, col3`. The values for each key is a list of numbers in the corresponding column of the dataframe.

What is the most efficient way to do this if the dataframe is huge?